# Serde deserialize String into u64

Tags: rust, serialization, serde

I can't find how to deserialize a JSON string into an integer type using `serde`.
My attempt won't compile:

```rust
#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
struct WebsocketMessage {
    #[serde(deserialize_with = "str::parse")]
    timestamp: u64
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, `str::parse` simply doesn't have the right type. The type must be

```
fn<'de, D>(D) -> Result<T, D::Error> where D: Deserializer<'de>
```

as documented [here](https://serde.rs/field-attrs.html).

So this function would work:

```
fn parse<'de, T, D>(de: D) -> Result<T, D::Error>
where
    D: serde::Deserializer<'de>,
    T: std::str::FromStr,
    <T as std::str::FromStr>::Err: std::fmt::Display,
{
    Ok(String::deserialize(de)?
        .parse()
        .map_err(serde::de::Error::custom)?)
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=9003657b60dd593f6920d09ad7e31f40)

But really, you'll have an easier time by using the `serde_with` crate:

```rust
use serde_with::{DisplayFromStr, serde_as};

#[serde_as]
#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
struct WebsocketMessage {
    #[serde_as(as = "DisplayFromStr")]
    timestamp: u64,
}
```

`serde_with` also has some nice options for parsing timestamps, so you don't even have to use `u64`.